# Bibliography in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I want to put the word "bibliography" at the end of my slides for a Chinese project, but I'm not sure what the correct word is. I searched online and found this translation on google translate:

> 参考书目

But I'm not sure if it is reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `参考文献`, it seems natural and adequate.